# Вывод ошибки при обмене Steam в консоль

Tags: c#, steam-web-api

Использую библиотеку CSharpTradeOffers ([GitHub](https://github.com/FatherFoxxy/CSharpTradeOffers))

В ней есть функции

`SendTradeOfferWithLink` (CSharpTradeOffers/Trading/EconServiceHandler.cs) и `SendOfferResponse` (CSharpTradeOffers/Trading/Data Classes/SendOfferResponse.cs)

У меня следующий код:

```
TradeOffer offer = new TradeOffer();
offer.Me.Assets.Add(csgoInventory.Items.First().Value.Items.First().ToCEconAsset(730));
var response = offerHandler.SendTradeOfferWithLink(steamid, token, msg, "1", offer, _account.AuthContainer);
Console.WriteLine(response.Error);
```

`SendTradeOfferWithLink` возвращает `SendOfferResponse`, в котором есть `Error` и `JsonProperty("strError")`

Мне необходимо выводить в консоль, если при попытке отправить обмен возникает какая-нибудь ошибка (например, [такая](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU8MN.jpg)). Но почему-то `response.Error` возвращает null, а в случае, если обмен не отправился из-за подобной ошибки - в консоль вообще ничего не выводится.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как мне вывести этот самый Error?

Comment: Может быть, имеет смысл спросить разработчиков библиотеки? Ваша библиотека довольно экзотическая, не думаю, что многие из участников ей пользовались.

Comment: Ну, может кому-то хватит просто общих знаний в программировании, чтобы подсказать, где ошибка))

Comment: Думаю, вопрос не в общих знаниях, а в том, каким образом библиотека возвращает ошибки. То есть это внутренняя подробность кухни этой самой библиотеки.

Comment: Так я ведь именно поэтому указал ссылку на гитхаб и местоположение  [EconServiceHandler.cs](https://github.com/FatherFoxxy/CSharpTradeOffers/blob/master/CSharpTradeOffers/Trading/EconServiceHandler.cs) и [SendOfferResponse](https://github.com/FatherFoxxy/CSharpTradeOffers/blob/master/CSharpTradeOffers/Trading/Data%20Classes/SendOfferResponse.cs)

Comment: Вы предлагаете нам разобраться в чужом коде? Прошерстить весь проект, _это же так просто_, найти ту часть, которая отвечает за ошибки, разобраться, что именно в ней не так, и написать ответ? Вы просите довольно многого. А что вы сами сделали? Вы уже начали исследование кода на гитхабе? Расскажите о том, что у вас есть к текущему моменту.